# Trying to install Flatcam on Ubuntu 20.04 but some dependencies are broken

Tags: 20.04, python

Trying to install Flatcam on Ubuntu 20.04 but some dependencies are broken, but I could fix some. Now I stopped here

```
dell@dell-inspiron1525:~/Downloads/flatcam$ python FlatCAMApp.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FlatCAMApp.py", line 11, in <module>
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
ImportError: No module named request
```

Can someone help me to continue with the installation ?

Comment: What is FlatCAM? From where?

Comment: FlatCAM is a software to convert gerber files to gcode and so you can use a cnc mill or 3D printer to produce PCB.

Comment: Can you verify if you executed the `setup_ubuntu.sh` bash script, which installs relevant system packages?

Comment: Hi Seth. Ubuntu 20.04 does not include PtQy4, so I installed manually. The same for python-shapely  and python-pip . After that, I edited the file setup_ubuntu.sh and deleted the line for each one of those. The problem is the urllib.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly Ubuntu related, but I can try answer anyway.

It looks to me that you didn't install all dependencies via pip prior to running the script/software.

```bsh
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This installs all packages listed in the requirements.txt file in the root of the repository, which should hopefully resolve all modules necessary to run it.

Run that, then try again, it should hopefully be fine.

Comment: Tried, but everything seems to be Ok

Comment: dell@dell-inspiron1525:~/Downloads/flatcam$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.4)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=1.3.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: shapely>=1.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.7.0)

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: simplejson in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (3.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rtree in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (0.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: svg.path in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 10)) (3.0)
dell@dell-inspiron1525:~/Downloads/flatcam$

Comment: I see, I just pulled a Docker image of Python 3.9.1, executed `./setup_ubuntu.sh` and `pip install -r requirements.txt`. That's already enough for me to be able to import `urllib.request` in a Python shell. See comment on the original question.